# XCode6, iOS8 how to scroll a size class enabled view controller to see offscreen elements within interface builder?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, uistoryboard, size-classes

I have a project that uses iOS8 storyboards with size classes. One of the view controllers contains a scroll view with a bunch of subviews. Part of them are hidden off screen. I can't seem to find a way to resize the view controller window - it is stuck at 600x600.

**Is there a way for me to scroll inside a view controller displayed on a storyboard to see elements that are currently off screen? (As if in a scroll view).**

In other words, I want to be able to scroll to be able to use interface builder to work with the stack views that are at the bottom of the view controller.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean Xcode 7 / iOS 9..  Stack Views aren't available in Xcode 6 / iOS 8..

Comment: Yeah, the principle is the same, I just said iOS8, because this is when size classes were introduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way for you to 'scroll', but you can change the simulated size in the "Size Inspector"

[image]

Comment: right, I changed size to freeform, but left pixel sizes as 600x600

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `y` for the view inside the scroll view to give value < 0 (for example -200)
[image]